# Why did my Gmail default theme suddenly change today without action or warning?

Tags: gmail

This morning it gave

[image]

This afternoon it gives

[image]

Reselecting Default Theme fails to remedy this.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably because Google changed it, 'cos I find under Settings:

[image]

Why does Google think changing such without warning or permission is appropriate? Goodness only knows!